# Choosing 2 people from a group of 15, 10 consecutive times, without repeating the same two people.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I would like to choose two helpers from my class of 15, every class for 10 classes in a row. The same person can be a helper more than once, but I do not want to choose the same pair more than once. How many ways can I do this?

**Answer**: I know the number of ways to choose 2 of the 15 helpers from the class is $C(15, 2)$. To do this for ten classes in a row, I'm assuming there are $(C(15,2))^{10}$ possible ways.

My thought process is that I am suppose to use the Complement Rule here, but I'm not seeing exactly how to do this.

Comment: It should be $C(C(15,2),10)$

Comment: Your question is worded ambiguously. You are using _class_ in two different context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first day you choose ${15}\choose{2}$ choices..

On the second day, you have ${15}\choose{2}$$-1$ choices.

On the third day, you have ${15}\choose{2}$$-2$ choices.

....

On the tenth day, you have ${15}\choose{2}$$-9$ choices.

By the multiplication rule, the total number of choices you have is:

${15}\choose{2}$(${15}\choose{2}$$-1$)(${15}\choose{2}$$-2$).....(${15}\choose{2}$$-9)$

Answer (score 0):

In the first class, you have $\binom{15}{2}$ options. In the second, you have $\binom{15}{2} - 1$, and so on. Therefore the total number of ways you could choose 10 pairs without repetition out of 15 people **assuming different orderings are different** is $\prod_{i=0}^9 \left(\binom{15}{2} - i\right)=10!\cdot\binom{\binom{15}{2}}{10}$, or **assuming different orderings are *not* different**, $\binom{\binom{15}{2}}{10}$.

Another way of looking at it is that you want to choose $10$ options without repetition from the set of pairs from the class, where the set of pairs is of size $\binom{15}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, there are $\binom{15}{2}=105$ *distinct* pairs

Thus $\binom{105}{10} = 28848458598960$, ie [image]
possibilities for the $10$ consecutive classes, giving you more than enough choices to give you a headache!